# awaitTermination in threadpool doesn't terminate the thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading

```
 if (isDownloadLogRequired) {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        for (HostGenericServiceTicket hostGenericServiceTicket : hostGenericServiceTickets) {
            pool.submit(new DiagnosticLogDownloader(logNames, downloadTo, hostGenericServiceTicket));
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        try {
            pool.awaitTermination(downloadTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(MessageFormat.format("{0}: Reason: {1}", e.getClass()
                    .getSimpleName(), e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

if downloadTimeout is set to 180 seconds the threads should get killed and program should end right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The timeout is how much you want to wait. The threadpool will terminate when all its task are executed.

If you call `shutdown()`, the threadpool will not enqueue new jobs (but it won't stop the running jobs, and will run jobs that are already enqueued).

If you call `shutdownNow()`, it will not start any new jobs and will send an interrupt to the working threads. If your `Runnable`s properly check for interrupts and terminate voluntarily, the pool will stop quickly. Otherwise, it's equivalent to `shutdown()`.

In Java, there is no way of forcedly terminating a thread (`Thread.stop()` is deprecated, because it's resource-leak and deadlock prone). You can only ask a thread to terminate (calling its `interrupt()` method), but it's up to your code to periodically check for `Thread.interrupted()` and properly using `InterruptedException`s.

An example of polite worker is something like:

```
public class PoliteWorker implements Runnable {
    private boolean successful = false;
    public void run() {
        while (...) {
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                myLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread was interrupted. Aborting...");
                return;
            }
            ...
            try {
                String line = myInput.readLine();
            } catch (InterruptedIOException ex) {
                //Must terminate
                myLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread was interrupted. Aborting...", ex);
                return;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //handle other exceptions
            }
        }
        successful = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But then why is the description of this API like this? - boolean awaitTermination(long timeout,
                         TimeUnit unit)
                         throws InterruptedException 
 Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout 
  occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I said "whichever happens first". It does not  actually do anything to terminate the threads.

Comment: then the program should move forward after the timeout and end right?... it should block only for the timeout amount of seconds and then should move forward... and when my program dies all threads should die with it right?... I mean in my case timeout happens first... so the code no more blocks on this call and moves forward right?

Comment: No. The threads of the threadpool are not background threads. So, they will live on, even if the thread that started them terminates. If you want your executor to use background threads, you can pass a custom `ThreadFactory` to it. But even so, the pool might not terminate, because it may use a "manager" thread, which is a foreground thread (I'm not sure of this last thing)

Comment: ok so my program won't exit then? I mean it's fine if the threads keep running but atleast the program should stop blocking and exit right?

Comment: If you want the application to terminate along with all its threads, then call `System.exit()`.

Comment: but what will happen if I don't call it... will the application exit leaving back executing threads? or if they are not background threads then the application will itself keep running...?

Comment: @Manav The main thread will terminate, but the process will not. A process terminates when `System.exit` is called, or when all its foreground threads terminate. I don't know what you technically mean by the term "application".

Comment: so suppose I am running the application from linux console... on the console I will not get my prompt back till the time process doesn't end or will I get it back sincs the main thread has ended...?

Comment: You will not get your prompt back.

Comment: Thanks I'll confirm this one more time... but what you suggested to my initial question is absolutely correct and thanks for that... :)